# Error : Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a problem with my TypeScript code :

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0:

First of all the error in browser console is this:
[image]

**The error in TypeScript as browser says:**

```
    roleMatch(allowedRoles): boolean {
  var isMatch = false;
  var userRoles: string[] = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userRoles'));
  allowedRoles.forEach(element => {
    if (userRoles.indexOf(element) > -1) {
      isMatch = true;
      return false;
    }
  });
  return isMatch;
}
```

**and the other part which is wrong too:**

```
canActivate(
  next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
  if (localStorage.getItem('userToken') != null) {
    let roles = next.data["roles"] as Array<string>;
    if (roles) {
      var match = this.userService.roleMatch(roles);
      if (match) return true;
      else {
        this.router.navigate(['/forbidden']);
        return false;
      }
    }
    else
      return true;
  }
  this.router.navigate(['/login']);
  return false;
}
```

Comment: What are the raw strings in `localStorage.getItem('userRoles')` and `localStorage.getItem('userToken')`

Comment: I'm guessing that `localStorage.getItem('userRoles')` returns `undefined`, which cannot be parsed

Comment: You can look at your local storage in the dev tools of the browser.

Comment: You have to check localStorage.getItem('userRoles') value in order to use JSON.parse.

Answer (score 2):

As [user184994](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52098378/error-unexpected-token-u-in-json-at-position-0#comment91147264_52098378) said, `localStorage.getItem('userRoles')` is most likely returning `undefined`.

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0:
>   is means that the JSON parser is failing at position 0 because the letter `u` was found.

The JSON must be of a valid [JSON data type](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_datatypes.asp).

You may want to initialize `userRoles` to an empty array.

```
var userRoles: string[] = [];
var userRolesStr = localStorage.getItem('userRoles');
if (userRolesStr) {
  userRoles = JSON.parse(userRolesStr);
}
```